# New to Python, write a text file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to programming. I am trying to create a program where I can type in details of a client and it gives me text output in a file. Everything works as planned except that it gives me a error when I try to add the EndDate in this line:

```
[EndDate+','+Email+','+PassWord+','+i+'\n'+Cell+','+Name+Message1+','+Name]
text_file.writelines(lines))
```

Here is my program.

```
from datetime import datetime
i=str(raw_input('StartingDate: '))
try:
dt_start=datetime.strptime(i,'%Y%m%d')


except ValueError:
print'Incorrect Format'

from datetime import timedelta
EndDate = dt_start+timedelta(days=1)
print EndDate



Name = raw_input ('Name: ')
SurName = raw_input ('SurName: ')
Cell = raw_input ('CellNo: ')
EmailAdd = raw_input ('Email: ')

Time = raw_input ('MessageTime: ')
Blank = raw_input ('------------- ')


Email = 'douwecoertze1@gmail.com'
PassWord ='oxoxoxox7'
x = 'Hallo '
Message1 = ',lekker dag'
Message2 = ' enjoy'


text_file = open ("write_it1.txt", "w")
lines = [EndDate+','+Email+','+PassWord+','+i+'\n'+Cell+','+Name+Message1+','+Name]
text_file.writelines(lines)
text_file.close()

text_file = open ("write_it2.txt", "w")
lines = [Email+','+PassWord+','+i+'\n'+Cell+','+Name+Message2+','+Name]
text_file.writelines(lines)
text_file.close()

text_file = open("write_it3.txt", "w")
lines = [Name+','+SurName+'\n'+Time+'\n'+i+'\n'+Cell+'\n'+EmailAdd+'\n'+Blank]
text_file.writelines(lines)
text_file.close()


text_file = open("write_it3.txt", "r")
print text_file.read()
text_file.close()

text_file = open("write_itAll.txt", "a")
lines = [Name+','+SurName+'\n'+Time+'\n'+i+'\n'+Cell+'\n'+EmailAdd+'\n'+Blank]
text_file.writelines(lines)
text_file.close()

raw_input("Press<enter>")
```

Why do I get this error? How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you heard of loops?

Comment: There are a few problems with your 1st post. First, the code is not formatted correctly, making it difficult to follow. Next, you ask about an error, and don't state the error. Finally, the example is too long http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Try cleaning it up and then we can help

Comment: Giving us the error would be nice! Any chance its "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.timedelta' and 'str'"

Comment: You didn't post your actual email password, did you?

Comment: And Please delete the password and change it as well (if it is the real one that you have written there in the code) :-)

Answer (score 0):

The error I guess is - unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.datetime' and 'str'

Just do str(EndDate) like below and it should work.

```
[str(EndDate)+','+Email+','+PassWord+','+i+'\n'+Cell+','+Name+Message1+','+Name]
text_file.writelines(lines))
```

Let me know if it helps